# system is unuseable after a few minutes

Tags: pi-2

I installed openSUSE Thumbleweed on my Raspberry Pi 2. After starting the system, logging as root the console goes away after a few minutes and I got just a blinking underscore. Then the system does not react at any key press, expect SRTG + ALT + DLT that reboots the system. I also can't use my keyboard in GRUB boot menu.

Edit: I have used the Rawrite32 from the NetBSD guys to get the .raw.xz image on the sd using windows. Then I was able to boot up the raspberry pi 2. It has then installed openSUSE Thumbleweed on the sd card and have created partitions on it. After that, I got also the only the blinking underscore. After a while of waiting, I pressed SRTG + ALT + DLT. I followed the instructions frome here: https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi2

Comment: Okay.  Please add details such as whether the Pi has ever worked and what has changed since it did work.

Comment: What about other systems on the same device?

Comment: openSUSE is my preferred linux distro. Fedora would be also nice. Or Ubuntu as the last choice.

Comment: I did not ask about your preferences. I asked if the device, which you claim you have problem with, has problems running other systems than openSUSE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was the operating system itself. I changed to Fedora Workstation and everything works like a charm. Maybe we should report this bug to openSUSE.